# Split string parameter to a define and a string

Tags: c

My iprintf function repeats the same string e.g.:

```
iprintf("[USER] created user:%d", userID);
iprintf("[USER] user disconnected:%d, userID");
```

I am trying to save some space and do something like this

```
const char strUser[] = "[USER]";
iprintf(strUser + "created user:%d", userID);
iprintf(strUser + "user disconnected:%d", userID);
```

What in C language can replace the "+" so it will work?

I am trying to keep at least part of the string as a parameter.

And do it during compilation with no extra functions

Comment: what about `iprintf("%s user disconnected:%d", strUser, userID)`

Comment: Thanks, Anyway I can save  the 2 bytes as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "save some space"? Do you want to reduce number of character in code?
Have you heard/tried macro?

Comment: Sure, I know some about MACRO, but how can they help me here? can I do MARO1+MACRO2?

Comment: You can do `printf(MACRO1 " user disconnected: %d", userID);` if the macro is a string literal.

Comment: But won't the MACRO1 will be replaced by string in all the places? causing the same space waist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If and how much space any attempt at optimization saves depends on the compiler. There is usually an option for a "minimum size build". Compiling the program and checking the results is the only method to see if space was truly saved. There is a good chance that any compiler, aiming for a minimum size build, that sees `const char strUser[] = "[USER] ";` will create exactly one string in the program, and point to that string wherever it is used.

Here are three options you could try. One using a macro, one using a function, and one using a different function call. I know you asked for "during compilation with no extra functions", but this function may very well be "optimized away" during compilation.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
#define IPRINTF1(format, args...) printf("[USER] " format, ##args);

// An iprintf wrapper that first prints the desired string.
void iprintf2(const char *restrict format, ...)
{
    printf("[USER] ");

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vprintf(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}

int main(void)
{
    const int userID = 5;
    const char strUser[] = "[USER] ";

    IPRINTF1("created user:%d\n", userID);
    iprintf2("created user:%d\n", userID);

    // Passing the string as an additional parameter.
    // This may be the best solution code quality-wise, as it avoids repetition while keeping the code dynamic.
    printf("%screated user:%d\n", strUser, userID);
}
```

Actually concatenating two strings with `+` as in Python is not possible in C. Instead there is the [strcat function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat). However, this involves allocating a buffer that is large enough, making a copy of the `format` string, always guaranteeing that the `restrict` qualifier holds... This is almost certainly not worth it.

Also, this is all under the assumption that saving a couple of bytes is worth the decrease in code quality.

Comment: Thanks, I can't figure out why  const char strUser[] = "[USER] " is better than const char* strUser = "[USER]" ? The latter show no difference in size in my project...

Comment: And won't IPRINTF1 replaced everywhere will add "[USER] " to all those places?

Comment: @schantischul Using `[]` creates the (short) string on the stack and makes it part of the code (`movabs  rax, 9109807186531675`) which may be slightly smaller than putting it in a read-only data segment and referring to that. But again, this depends on the compiler. You may want to play around with [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org) to see what the effect is. You may also want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s).

Comment: @schantischul Yes, the _preprocessor_ will copy the "[USER] " string literal everywhere the macro is used, but it is very likely that the compiler will afterwards notice that the same string appears in multiple places and will optimize this.

Comment: Thanks! 
But I am getting the weirdest behavior, I am passing the string as additional parameter. (%s)
On replacing some strings, I've noticed the size of the code gets bigger instead of smaller...
My optimization flag: -Og, how can this be explained..?

Comment: @schantischul What is "the weirdest behavior"? If necessary, open a new question with a minimal, reproducible example.